# Create one virtual volume (Storage Pool) from multiple machines (WinServ2012)

Tags: hyper-v, storage-spaces, windows-server-2012-r2, storage-pool

Is it possible to create one storage pool or virtual volume from all of the drives in several machines with Windows Server 2012?

I imagine this would come from creating a Storage Space on each machine, and then combining all of those Spaces on individual machines into one Storage Pool. That one Storage Pool would be manipulated from a controller server.

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to utilize DFS. Note: to the best of my knowledge the participating machines need to be on the same domain - not workgroup.

- Add this role from the Server Manager (Server Roles, File and Storage Services, DFS Replication).
- Start the DFS Management too. (press the Windows button then start typing "DFS Management").
- Right click on Replication.
- Click New Replication Group.
- Choose your desired Replication Group Type then click Next. (default sounds fine for what you're asking for though the other option enables hub and spoke style replication)
- Enter a name for the Replication Group and ensure the domain is correct then click Next.
- Next, add all of the servers you want to add to this pool then click Next.
- Topology: Full mesh will create good redundancy and will help with file access times. The downside is that you'll need to have the storage space for whatever you're aiming to do.
- Select your Primary member. I often aim for the biggest, baddest, most reliable piece of gear I have for this. Click Next.
- Select the path for replication, click Next.
- Local Path of (folder) on Other Members: click edit and select where you want the folder to be copied to on the other machines that you just selected. If you do not select a path here replication wont take place for that folder (do you want redundancy or just to make the pools available?)

This may not be all the info you need but it should definitely get you going in the right direction!